# jetty cannot start "unable to create the virtual machine" when I add the --exec parameter

Tags: java, jetty, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm getting this strangest of errors with Jetty.  When I try starting it I get "Unable to start virtual Machine" and next line say "Unrecognized Option: -".

I start it using a batch file containing simply java -jar start.jar and I have a ini file where basically everything is commented out with leaving only the --exec line.

If I comment also the --exec then Jetty starts, though without the java VM arguments my web app so desperately needs.

Strangest thing is that the exact same config run on all other system I tried it on without problems.

The problem machine is based on Windows server 2008 R2 running the 64 bit JDK 6u29.

I tried pretty much everything to no avail, searched to internet for a while for someone who might encountered a similar problem again without result.

Has any of you seen this or would you have suggestions as to how to tackle this issue.

---

EDIT:  Entered a [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=364924) in jetty`s bugzilla for this issue.

Comment: a dead end (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cul-de-sac)

Comment: lol, yes. I'm asking what it means in the context of java, jetty, and WS2008. Or are you just meaning "I'm stuck"?

Comment: yes, that's all there is too it :-)  Stuck in the mud, _i'm fallen and I can't get up_ kinna stuck !

Comment: I'm with you. :) But I've removed the tag, as the tags are for categorising the question rather than the current state of mind of the OP!

Comment: naaa it's all good, I guess I needed to vent a bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

found the problem...

quite simply it was because the path leading to that particular installation of jetty contained a space and a dash as such :

```
c:\toto\titi\server - prod\hereLiesJetty
```

also the --exec option must be turned on.  if the option is off everything runs fine, however you wont be able to customize your vm options.

that caused the this to fail when started through a batch file that used relative paths to locate the VM as it is packaged with the application.

removing the space in the path resolved the issue completely

```
c:\toto\titi\server-prod\hereLiesJetty
```

Quite easy to reproduce, just get the basic jetty -package and create a batch file it it's bin folder akin to

```
cd ..
java -jar start.jar
```

and double click on it..

boom...  end of the world !

darn...  so close yet so far away !  it's always the simplest things that get to us isn't it !!

Comment: FWIW, and you probably know already, but you can wrap the path in quotes to get round it too - eg "c:\toto\titi\server - prod\hereLiesJetty"

Comment: yes.... but no you see nowhere in my code batch file, config or otherwise this path appears.  It must be dynamically extracted and used by the start.jar.  That is how I usually handle this situation but in this case I have nowhere to quote the path as it appears nowhere.  i<m gonna have a go at the Jetty bug base and code base tomorrow see if I can't make heads or tails of this.  If all goes well perhaps even have a patch for them.